# How to get string from a list if a substring is present

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get products' images when clicked upon since they are higher resolution.  So far, I have this code:

```
start = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser') # d is the driver
while start.find('div', {'class': 'gallery-images'}) is None:
            start = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')

        product_images = [i.find('img', {'alt': 'Mirror Embellished Scuba Skirt'}).src for i in
                    start.find_all('div', {'class': 'gallery-images'})]
```

However, it says that nonetype has no object src.  start.find_all returns list of all the elements that are cascaded inside of it.

Edit: Webpage:
https://www.michaelkors.com/mirror-embellished-scuba-skirt/_/R-US_MU97EYCBGL

Edit 2: 
I have hardcoded value of alt. Page scrapy calls doesn't have alt with this specific value. But when I remove alt even then it isn't returning anything

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: Oops! Completely forgot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.It returns me `src` values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.michaelkors.co.uk/")
search_ele=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.search-link[title="Search"]')))
search_ele.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input#search-box'))).send_keys('mirror-embellished-scuba-skirt')
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.search-icon-btn')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[title="Mirror Embellished Scuba Skirt"]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
product_images=[]
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='gallery-images'):
    for img in i.select('img[alt="Mirror Embellished Scuba Skirt"]'):
        product_images.append(img['src'])

print(product_images)
```

**Output:**

```
['//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_1?wid=558&hei=748&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2&qlt=90', '//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_2?wid=558&hei=748&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2&qlt=90', '//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_3?wid=558&hei=748&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2&qlt=90', '//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_1?wid=1300', '//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_2?wid=1300', '//michaelkors.scene7.com/is/image/MichaelKors/MU97EYCBGL-0001_3?wid=1300']
```

Comment: What happens if alt changes? How can I generalize it?

Comment: If you want to fetch all images under div element.just remove the alt.put only  `i.select('img')`

Comment: `select()` is same as `find_all()` . `select()` is css selector for beautifulsoup.

Comment: Just removed alt altogether and it is giving me all the images. Thanks a ton! it worked